# how i get the object form an array with a parameter function like this

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I will only get an object  in comparison the id that from is decided from the user with objects of the arrays.

```
var laptops = [{
    "name": "Firefox",
    "age": 30,
    "id": "ab"
  },
  {
    "name": "Google",
    "age": 35,
    "id": "cd",
    "date": "00.02.1990"
  },
  {
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "id": "ef",
    "age": 40
  }
];


getLaptopByAsin(id: string) {
  var laptop = this.laptops.find(
    (laptopObject) => {
      return laptopObject.name === id;
    }
  );
  return laptop;
}
var enter = "cd";
name = this.getLaptopByAsin(enter).name;
age = this.getLaptopByAsin(enter).age;
date = this.getLaptopByAsin(enter).date;
console.log(name)
console.log(age)
console.log(date)
```

Comment: `laptopObject.name === id;` should be `laptopObject.id === id;`

Comment: Also you can simply your function like this: `return this.laptops.find(lo => lo.id === id);`

Comment: after change i receive this like error message : Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you filter on name:

```
this.laptops.find(
    (laptopObject) => {
      return laptopObject.name === id;
    }
 );
```

After fixing your issue and do some refactoring, the code becomes this:

```
getLaptopByAsin(id: string) {
  return this.laptops.find(
    laptopObject => laptopObject.id === id
  );
}
```

Some other comments:

- Try to use const instead of var more often where possible.
- Saving date the way you do, might give you some headache in the future. use some standard instead, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch
- Avoid multiple function calls when they are not needed, save the result from getLaptopByAsin to a variable (const foundLaptop) so you don't need to iterate over the array multiple times. eg:

  const foundLaptop = this.getLaptopByAsin('cd');
  console.log(foundLaptop.name);
  console.log(foundLaptop.age, foundLaptop.date);

Comment: after change i receive this like error message : Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Works for me tho, could you share the code you try to use?

Comment: as the project code is much long, But what i try to do is to send data from one component to another with route in Angular ... if you want i can try to push this here